# jQuery adding an <tr> line when loading / jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, asynchronous

I have a table built that comes from data in the server. I have a button that will activate or deactivate a category. If the category is active, it will show the action of "inactivate" and so the way around. So I need the table to refresh so when the user clicks activate it will automatically switch. I am almost done with this. Issue is that when I use the jQuery load function, it seems like it's adding one additional  line instead of just refreshing it.

This is my code, I send a request to the server, then wait for it to finish to load.

My code is below:

```
 async function cambiarStatus(tipo_transa, ruta, estadoCat, idCat, div, file) 
 {    
     await modStat(tipo_transa, ruta, estadoCat, idCat);
     $(div).load(file+div);
 }
```

With the table I built with PHP I only have one ... but then it goes and another one which ends up in making the table go nuts.

Many thanks for your help!!!!!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I post a question here so I couldnt put the image correctly. but click the link to see how the code goes crazy. thank you!

Comment: I'm not seeing any useful code here sorry

Comment: Please show the code where `div` gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to guess that the value of the variable `div` is something like `#c-i-1`, or `#` plus the `id` of whichever table row you're trying to replace.

In that case, the code as written is telling jQuery to replace the *content* of the table row, not the table row itself, with the matching table row loaded from the file. That's going to cause exactly the problem you're showing, a table row being put inside a table row.

You need to replace the table row itself with the retrieved table row. For that, as convenient as jQuery's `load` method is, it doesn't offer the functionality you need.

Something like this should work better:

```
$.get(file, table => {
    const row = $(table).find(div);
    $(div).replaceWith(row);
});
```